# Transforming a flow of PagingData from paging3 into a StateFlow of PagingData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

I am learning pagination using paging3 from the jetpack library. I am making a call to an api to receive a list of articles. I've noticed that the result received after making the call in the repository using the Pager is a flow of  PagingData containing the desired result like so:

```
Flow<PagingData<Articles>>
```

When I receive this flow in my ViewModel I would like to convert it into a Stateflow. I have tried using the **stateIn** operator but it requires a default value which I think would be a StateFlow , this is where I am stuck. How can I convert the flow of PagingData into a Stateflow and is it advisable to do so?

Comment: Why do you need to convert this to a `StateFlow`?

Comment: I think It´s interesting question. How can I handle an initial state or error state without StateFlow in this case?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483347/android-mvi-using-stateflow-and-paging-3 This user suggests to use flow inside a success state of stateFlow but I don´t think is the best solution. Any other?

Answer (score 1):

I also have a question: why do you want to convert the Flow of PagingData into a Stateflow when you get the Article and show them on UI?

In my practice, no need to touch Stateflow. If I want to get Articles with Paging lib 3. Pay attention to `Flow`, `ArticleRemoteMediator: RemoteMediator<Int, ArticleEntity>` ...

I think this article can help you to archive your goal. (getting article with Paging 3) https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/pagination-in-android-with-paging-3-retrofit-and-kotlin-flow-2c2454ff776e

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the usecase, while using regular flow every new subscriber triggers a new flow emission this can lead to resource wastage (unnecessary network requests) on configuration change eg screen ration, if you would desire such a behaviour its okey to use regular if not consider using StateFlow.
You can convert a regular flow emissions into StateFlow by using `stateIn` extension and set the initial state as empty as follows.

```kotlin
someFlow.stateIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), PagingData.empty())
```

According to the documentation `PagingData.empty()` immediately displays an empty list of items with dispatching any load state update to a presenter